# "DatabaseIOException: File system error (12)" when using database?

Tags: java, blackberry

I have created a tab bar which appears when I enter first time in database screen, this code is working fine. But when we go on another tab and again go on database screen tab it throws an exception

net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseIOException: File system error (12)

I have closed database properly.

I Have close database in finally block.Database is closing each time when I am moving the tab

This is my code:

```
    Database d = null;
    URI _uri = null;
    Statement st = null;
    Cursor c = null;

    try
    {

         _uri=URI.create("file:///SDCard/MyBudgetTracker.db");
            if (DatabaseFactory.exists(_uri)) {
                d=DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(_uri,new DatabaseSecurityOptions(false));
                 st = d.createStatement("SELECT * FROM "+Globalvalue.planCategoryTable);
                st.prepare();
                 c = st.getCursor();
                Row r;
                int i = 0;

                while(c.next()) {
                    r = c.getRow();
                    r.getString(0);
                    i++;
                }
                if (i==0)
                {
                    add(new RichTextField("No data in the User table."));
                }

        }


    }catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();// TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        try {
            if (DatabaseFactory.exists(_uri)) {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                } if (d != null) {
                    d.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: While you are closing cursor or statement you could get another error. Since all of the closing code is in same try/catch you have chance don't close the database itself.

Answer (score -1):

You are retrieving values onto your selected tab from database?
You can think of this alternative method of opening and closing database.It always yields lesser errors.

```
try
{    
    //Open or create the database
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate("MyBudgetTracker.db");    
    //Retrieve Data from db
    Statement statement1 = db.createStatement("SELECT * FROM "+Globalvalue.planCategoryTable);
    statement1.prepare();
    statement1.execute();       
    statement1.close(); 
    db.close();
}
catch(DatabaseException dbe)
{
    System.err.println(dbe.toString());
}
```

Else you can include a db open statement on each of ur tabs before u fetch the value albeit it wud increase ur programming code lines.

Comment: I don't think that this approach is better. Db might be not closed properly in case of errors.